# Typescript - Detect sentences in an non consecutive array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm

I'm trying to detect sentences in an array of words to determine which ones are unique.

Right know my function is able to detect sentences but only if the words in the array are consecutive, example:

```
const words: Words[] = [
  { id: 1, content: "Date" },
  { id: 2, content: "of" },
  { id: 3, content: "my" },
  { id: 4, content: "Birthday" },
  { id: 5, content: "Date" },
  { id: 6, content: "of" },
  { id: 7, content: "his" },
  { id: 8, content: "Birthday" },
];
```

function findText:

```
function findText(searchStr: string, words: any[]) {
  const cleanEnding = (word: string) => {
    return word.replace(/[\s:;]*$/, '');
  };
  const cleanStart = (word: string) => {
    return word.replace(/^[\s]*/, '');
  }
  const getAliases = (word: string) => {
    return [word, word.replace('i', '1'), word.replace('i', 'l')];
  };

  searchStr = '' + cleanEnding(searchStr);

  const wordsString: string = words.map((w) => {
    w.content = cleanStart(cleanEnding(w.content));
    return w.content.toLowerCase()
  }).join(" ");

  const splitString = wordsString.split(" ");
  const splitSearch = searchStr.toLowerCase().split(" ");

  let idxs: number[] = [];
  splitString.forEach((string, idx) => {
    splitSearch.forEach((search) => {
      if (string === search) {
        const possibleMatch = splitString.slice(
          idx,
          idx + splitSearch.length,
        );     
        splitSearch.join(" ") === possibleMatch.join(" ") &&  getAliases(possibleMatch.join(" ").toLowerCase()).includes(splitSearch.join(" ").toLowerCase()) &&
          idxs.push(idx);
      }
    });
  });

  const result: any[] = [];

  if (idxs.length === 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < splitSearch.length; i++) {
      result.push(
        words[idxs[0] + i]
      );

    }
    return result;
  } else if (idxs.length > 1) {

    for (let i = 0; i < idxs.length; i++) {
      let sub: any[] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < splitSearch.length; j++) {
        sub.push(
          words[idxs[i] + j]
        );
      }
      result.push(sub)
    }
    return result;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

`const result = findText("Date of his", words)` returns:

```
[
 { id: 5, content: 'Date' },  
 { id: 6, content: 'of' },
 { id: 7, content: "his" },
]
```

`const result = findText("Date of", words)` returns:

```
[
  [ { id: 1, content: 'Date' },  { id: 2, content: 'of' }],
  [ { id: 5, content: 'Date' },  { id: 6, content: 'of' }],
]
```

`const result = findText("Date of abc", words)` returns:

```
null
```

I would like it to behave the same when given an non-consecutive array, any idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you're overcomplicating things. If you only want to check a word is present in the array, can you not use the Array.find() or Array.filter() helpers after you split the string? Maybe I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "consecutive" vs "non-consecutive" in the context of arrays. The elements in all these arrays are consecutive, i.e. the arrays are not sparse. At present, I can't tell whether the problem you're focused on is about data structures or data sets.

Comment: I guess i did what you needed...

Comment: You really need to explain what you mean by "non-consecutive".  Should `"Date of"` now return `[[{id: 1,...}, {id: 2,...}], [{id: 1,...}, {id: 6,...}], [{id: 5,...}, {id: 1,...}], [{id: 5,...}, {id: 6,...}]]`?  Would `"of of of"` fail because there are only two `"of"` in the list?  What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this suits your needs:

```js
const words = [
    { id: 8, content: 'Birthday' },
    { id: 1, content: 'Date' },
    { id: 3, content: 'my' },
    { id: 9, content: 'Date' },
    { id: 5, content: 'Date' },
    { id: 6, content: 'of' },
    { id: 2, content: 'of' },
    { id: 4, content: 'Birthday' },
    { id: 7, content: 'his' },
];

function findText(search_string, word_array) {
    let words_of_seach_string = search_string.split(' ');

    let found_words = [];

    words_of_seach_string.forEach((search_word) => {
        let foundWordsTemp = word_array.filter((word) => word.content.toLowerCase() === search_word.toLowerCase());
        found_words = found_words.concat(foundWordsTemp);
    });

    let possible_sentences = [];
    let sentence_temp = [];

    let done_searching = false;
    while (!done_searching) {
        words_of_seach_string.forEach((search_word) => {
            let first_word_found = found_words.filter(
                (word) => word.content.toLowerCase() === search_word.toLowerCase()
            )[0];
            if (!first_word_found) return;
            sentence_temp.push(first_word_found);
            let array_without_this_element = found_words.filter((word) => word.id !== first_word_found.id);
            found_words = array_without_this_element;
        });

        if (sentence_temp.length === words_of_seach_string.length) {
            possible_sentences.push([...sentence_temp]);
        }

        sentence_temp = [];

        done_searching = found_words.length < words_of_seach_string.length;
    }

    return possible_sentences;
}

//TEST PART
function testSentenceAndLog(sentence) {
    console.log(sentence, findText(sentence, words));
}

testSentenceAndLog('Date of');
testSentenceAndLog('my birthday');
testSentenceAndLog('birthday OF');
testSentenceAndLog('DATE');
testSentenceAndLog('date my his');
testSentenceAndLog('Date Date');
testSentenceAndLog('Date of HIS');
testSentenceAndLog('Date of abc');
```